# How to delete an array with an int ptr pointing to it

Tags: c++

Hi so I have something like:

```
int *p=new int[3];
*p=1;
p++;
*p=2;
delete [] p;
```

Is this the correct way to delete the array that p is pointing to?

Comment: No. That's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `delete` on the middle of the array which is undefined behavior. In this simple case you'd just need to go back to the start of the array

```
delete [] (p - 1);
```

You should adjust your code to use indexing

```
p[0] = 1;
p[1] = 2;
```

Or just make a copy of the pointer

```
auto p2 = p;
*p2 = 1;
++p2;
*p2 = 2;
delete [] p;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you are `delete`ing a pointer that you did not `new`.  You've changed the value the original pointer you `new`ed.

The correct way to do that is:

```
int* p = new int[3];
p[0] = 1;
p[1] = 2;
delete[] p;
```

In that case you keep the original pointer to the memory you allocated.

If you really need to do arithmetic on your pointer you should save the original value so that you can pass it to `delete[]`.

```
int* p = new int[3];
int* orig = p;
*p = 1;
p++;
*p = 2;
delete[] orig;
```